# Daphne websocket disconnects when trying to send message

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis, channel

**LONG STORY SHORT:**
Cant send message in django channels becuase daphne disconnects. This only occurs for large loads and only since i switched to redis channel layers instead of in memory.

In detail:
My websocket keeps disconnecting if I run a more resource heavy process. The websocket consumer processes a file and checks if it is in the correct format and returns and a status update, eg "Correct format", "Missing columns", etc. If I delete 20% of the rows from a file that caused the websocket to disconnect it works. I managed to narrow it down to around 500Kb is where the limit is. And also other consumers work too.

**CHANNELS:**
The issue occured when I changed from the dev `InMemoryChannelLayer` to `RedisChannelLayer` so thats why I think that the error is somewhere in that area and not with the specific consumer or process. The channel layers config is pretty simple, just the basic Redis example fromt the docs:

```py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(os.environ.get("REDIS_HOST"), 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

I tried setting stuff like `capacity`, `expiry`, `group_expiry`, `channel_capacity` but nothing worked.\

**REDIS**: 
The redis server is running, if i do `redis-cli ping` it returns `PONG`.
Configs:

- `maxmemory`: 0
- `tcp-keepalive`: 300
- `maxclients`: 10000
- `timeout`: 0

**ERROR:**
I managed to find out by logging that the error occurs when sending data. There is not too much info in the daphne logs. I get this message:

> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:   File "/home/atti/googleds/ds/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 539, in parse_resp>
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:     response = await connection.read_response()
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:   File "/home/atti/googleds/ds/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 782, in read_r>
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:     response = await self._parser.read_response(
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:   File "/home/atti/googleds/ds/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 411, in read_r>
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:     await self.read_from_socket()
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:   File "/home/atti/googleds/ds/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 394, in read_f>
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]:     raise ConnectionError(SERVER_CLOSED_CONNECTION_ERROR) from None
> Jul 28 07:31:29 googleds-server daphne[734093]: redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.

Or this:

> Jul 28 05:10:17 googleds-server daphne[722072]: 127.0.0.1:59088 - - [28/Jul/2023:04:49:28] "WSREJECT /ws/upload/14857/" - -
> Jul 28 05:10:17 googleds-server daphne[722072]: 127.0.0.1:59088 - - [28/Jul/2023:04:49:28] "WSDISCONNECT /ws/upload/14857/"

The error code with which it closes is **1006**. I haven't managed to find out more.

Is there some config that I don't know about for setting max load? I have been stuck on this for a week now, would greatly appriciate some help. I went through every doc, stackoverflow question, even tried arguing wiht some ai but nothing really worked. I tried optimizing the consumer, but I uploaded/checked 15 Mb excel files up until this point and there is no way that I'm going to make it 30 times more efficient(currently the max I can do is 500Kb). Also, I don't even upload the file through the websocket, I pre-upload it through a normal HTTP API and I only read it with pandas in the consumer.

`consumers.py`:

```py
class UploadConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        self.upload_id = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["upload_id"]
        self.upload_group_name = 'upload_%s' % self.upload_id
        self.upload = await self.get_upload()
        self.template = await self.get_template()
        file = self.upload.file
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.upload_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        print("WHILE START")
        filename, extension_format = os.path.splitext(str(self.upload.file))
        accepted_formats = [".xlsx", ".csv", ".xls", ".tsv"]
        if extension_format in accepted_formats:
            self.form_over_stat = True
        else:
            self.form_over_stat = False
        if not self.form_over_stat:
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.upload_group_name,
                {
                    "type": "status",
                    "extension_format": {
                        "overall_status": self.form_over_stat,
                        "gotten": extension_format,
                        "expected": ", ".join(accepted_formats),
                    },
                    "column_names": {
                        "overall_status": "",
                        "missing_cols": "",
                        "wrong_cols": "",
                        "gotten": "",
                        "expected": "",
                    },
                    "column_content": {
                        "overall_status": "",
                        "error": ""
                    }
                }
            )
        else:
            print("WHILE UPLOAD")
            if extension_format == '.csv':
                data = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=int(self.template.skiprows))
            elif extension_format == '.tsv':
                data = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=int(
                    self.template.skiprows), delimiter='\t')
            else:
                data = pd.read_excel(
                    file, skiprows=int(self.template.skiprows))
            print("WHILE D")
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            self.source_column_names_raw = {k: v for k, v in sorted(json.loads(
                self.template.source_column_names).items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
            self.source_column_names = ", ".join(
                list(self.source_column_names_raw.values()))
            self.gotten_column_names = ", ".join(df.columns.sort_values())
            self.wrong_cols = ", ".join(
                list(set(self.gotten_column_names.split(", ")) - set(self.source_column_names.split(", "))))
            print("WHILE C")
            if self.template.table == "pro_költségek":
                missing_cols = list(set(self.source_column_names.split(
                    ", ")) - set(self.gotten_column_names.split(", ")))
                cols_to_remove = [
                    "1_alkategoria", "2_alkategoria", "3_alkategoria", "4_alkategoria"]
                missing_cols = [
                    i for i in missing_cols if i not in cols_to_remove]
            else:
                missing_cols = list(set(self.source_column_names.split(
                    ", ")) - set(self.gotten_column_names.split(", ")))
            self.missing_cols = ", ".join(missing_cols)
            if self.missing_cols:
                self.column_over_stat = False
            else:
                self.column_over_stat = True
            numeric_cols = col_by_dtype(['decimal', 'numeric', 'real', 'double precision',
                                        'smallserial', 'serial', 'bigserial', 'money', 'bigint'], self.upload.table)
            print("WHILE B")
            date_cols = col_by_dtype(['date', 'timestamp'], self.upload.table)
            numeric_cols_source = [
                j for i, j in self.source_column_names_raw.items() if i in numeric_cols] if numeric_cols else []
            date_cols_source = [
                j for i, j in self.source_column_names_raw.items() if i in date_cols] if date_cols else []
            column_content_stat = True
            column_content_error = []
            if self.template.table == 'fol_gls_elszámolás':
                df = df[df['Súly'].notna()]
            print("WHILE A")
            for i in df.columns:
                try:
                    if numeric_cols_source and i in numeric_cols_source:
                        lst = []
                        for x in df[i]:
                            if type(x) == str and ',' in x:
                                lst.append(x.replace(',', '.'))
                            else:
                                lst.append(x)
                        df[i] = lst
                        df[i] = df[i].astype(float)
                    if date_cols_source and i in date_cols_source:
                        df[i] = df[i].astype(dtype='datetime64[ns]')
                except ValueError as e:
                    column_content_stat = False
                    column_content_error.append(
                        {"error_col": str(i), "error": str(e)})
            # This is the last print that gets logged
            print("WHILE SENDING")
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.upload_group_name,
                {
                    "type": "status",
                    "extension_format": {
                        "overall_status": self.form_over_stat,
                        "gotten": extension_format,
                        "expected": ", ".join(accepted_formats),
                    },
                    "column_names": {
                        "overall_status": self.column_over_stat,
                        "missing_cols": self.missing_cols,
                        "wrong_cols": self.wrong_cols,
                        "gotten": self.gotten_column_names,
                        "expected": self.source_column_names,
                    },
                    "column_content": {
                        "overall_status": column_content_stat,
                        "error": column_content_error
                    }
                }
            )
            print("FINISHED")

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_template(self):
        return DatauploadTabletemplates.objects.get(table=self.upload.table)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_upload(self):
        return DatauploadUploadmodel.objects.get(id=self.upload_id)

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.upload_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        if json.loads(text_data)["upload"]:
            await self.set_upload_status()

    @database_sync_to_async
    def set_upload_status(self):
        upload = DatauploadUploadmodel.objects.get(id=self.upload_id)
        setattr(upload, "status", "ready")
        setattr(upload, "status_description", "Feltöltésre vár")
        upload.save()

    async def status(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            "extension_format": {
                        "overall_status": event["extension_format"]["overall_status"],
                        "gotten": event["extension_format"]["gotten"],
                        "expected": event["extension_format"]["expected"],
                        },
            "column_names": {
                "overall_status": event["column_names"]["overall_status"],
                "missing_cols": event["column_names"]["missing_cols"],
                "wrong_cols": event["column_names"]["wrong_cols"],
                "gotten": event["column_names"]["gotten"],
                "expected": event["column_names"]["expected"],
            },
            "column_content": {
                "overall_status": event["column_content"]["overall_status"],
                "error": event["column_content"]["error"]
            }
        }))
```